# Oracle DataAccess OracleUDTDescriptor random failures

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, odp.net, user-defined-types, oracle-spatial

We have a number of .NET applications that use the Oracle Data Provider for .NET. This generally works fine, but occassionally we get a burst of errors from one particular application (sometimes other but very rarely), where its claiming something went wrong with the Oracle Data Access Client. The errors are sometimes slightly different, but all relate to User Defined Types. One example of a failure would be;

> Inner Exception:
>
> **Message**: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> **Source**: Oracle.DataAccess
>
> **Stack Trace**:
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdtDescriptor.get_UdtTypeName()
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.RetrieveSchemaTable(DataTable&
>   dataTable, Boolean isFromEx)
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetSchemaTableCopy(DataTable&
>   dataTable, Boolean isFromEx)
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetSchemaTable()

The SQL that causes this is;

```
SELECT a.SECTION_NO,
       INITCAP(a.SECTION_NAME) AS SECTION_NAME,
       a.SITE_USRN, 
       a.NETWORK_HIERARCHY,
       a.ROAD_CLASS,
       a.CENTRAL_ASSET_ID,
       a.GEOM,
       SDO_NN_DISTANCE(1) AS dist
FROM SCHEMANAME.TABLE_NAME a 
WHERE SDO_NN(a.GEOM, 
             sdo_geometry(2001, 27700, sdo_point_type(366646,101677,NULL), NULL, NULL), 'sdo_num_res=1',1) 
             = 'TRUE'
```

There's no pattern to when this happens, and 95% of the time these requests go through with no problem, but at least once a day this will happen. It'll keep occuring for 1 or 2 minutes (so I'll get 10-20 error alerts, all saying about the same thing), then it'll sort itself out and it'll be fine again. I really don't understand what the problem is. I don't know much about User Defined Types, and searching for the particular error results in very few relevant results.

Another example of a similar error message we sometimes get;

> Inner Exception:
>
> **Message**: Object reference not set to an instance of
>   an object.
>
> **Source**: Oracle.DataAccess
>
> **Stack Trace**:
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdtDescriptor.GetMetaDataTable()
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetCachedOracleUdtDescriptor(Int32
>   index)
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.RetrieveSchemaTable(DataTable&
>   dataTable, Boolean isFromEx)
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetSchemaTableCopy(DataTable&
>   dataTable, Boolean isFromEx)
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetSchemaTable()

As you can see, they are similar, but not exactly the same which makes tracking it down even harder. The only possibilities I can think of is it is something to do with pulling back the GEOM column, but we do that in a huge number of places and don't get this error, or possibly something to do with pulling back the SDO_NN number, but again, we do that in multiple places with no errors.

As far as I can tell there are no special or exotic column types being returned there, apart from the GEOM, which, considering we are using Oracle Spatial, shouldn't be a problem.

One fix I have attempted is to add a setting to my Web.config called `StatementCacheWithUdts`.

```
<oracle.dataaccess.client>
    <settings>
        <add name="StatementCacheWithUdts" value="0"/>
    </settings>
</oracle.dataaccess.client>
```

This was based on a similar problem I found somewhere (cannot find the link anymore, stupidly forgot to write it down), but this didn't resolve the problem.

Does anyone have any pointers whatsoever as to what I can try?

**Further Details**

**Oracle version:** Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

**ODP.Net version:** 4.121.2.0 ODAC RELEASE 3

Comment: Well, first I would check to make sure there aren't earlier errors you are missing. Ideally you want to find the first ORA error you get. For example, maybe a connection is going stale somehow. If so, you would need to post those error numbers here and I can try to assist. Also, check on the database server side ALERT log to see if any errors are being reported there at the same timestamp. If it is reproducible in a small window of time, and a performance hit is ok, you could turn on ODP.NET tracing as well and look for the ORA error in there.

Comment: Possible causes are a server side error crashing the connection or other network glitches (eg firewall etc). You might need to apply database and client patches if it is the first. Please provide the full ODP.NET version and database version numbers.

Comment: @ChristianShay I've added the version numbers to the post. I'll ask our DBA to see if she can find any errors in the log, but she's away at the moment, hopefully be able to dig something out once we're back. Thanks for looking, any tiny insights is massively helpful!